# python print data to stout in the format python sees. IE raw.

Tags: python

The program hex.py (code is from hex.py) has previously loaded a hex.patch file which has 3 items of info 
1.the target file to open (in this case tar = a windows.exe file)
2.old (the data to find in the exe) 
3.new (the data to replace old in the exe). 
    The old/new will either be written as hex (64000000 or 6400 0000) or as text in who knows what format UTF8 UTF16?. 
    I need to be able to see the patch file 'old' and 'new' data and the tar file data in the same format that python does (BEFORE it translates it to me) so I can write the correction factor routines.
hex.py:

```
    modcwd = os.getcwd() #assign var to modman dir
    patch = 'hex.patch' #hardcode patch to var
    patlst = [line.strip() for line in open(patch,'rb',1)] #Read Patch start
    tar = patlst[patlst.index('TAR:')+1];old = patlst[patlst.index('OLD:')+1];new = patlst[  pat.index('NEW:')+1]
    #start sub to determine if data hex or alpha
    a = old [:8]
    count = lambda l1, l2: len(list(filter(lambda c: c in l2, l1)))
    a_chars =  count(a, string.ascii_letters) 
    a_digits = count(a, string.digits) 
    if (a_chars/a_digits) > .45 : alphex = 'a'
    else: alphex = 'h'
    if alphex == 'h' : old = ''.join(old.split()); new = ''.join(new.split())
    oldlc = [o.lower() for o in old];old = ''.join(oldlc)
    newlc = [n.lower() for n in new];new = ''.join(newlc)
    #load open exe file
    pircwd = os.chdir('..'); pircwd = os.getcwd()
    fotar = open(tar,'rb')
    data = fotar.read(160)
    Hdata = (binascii.hexlify(data))
    bus = re.sub(old,new,Hdata)
    fobus = open ('newhex','wb')
    fobus.write(bus)
    fobus.close()
    fotar.close()

The complete hex.patch :
TAR: 
Hex!.exe
OLD:
2068 6572 652C 2073 7765 6574 6965 2E0A
NEW:
2068 6572 652C 2073 6578 792E 2E2E 2E0A
EOF:
```

As of now it is finding the correct data, i.e 'old' = data(matching substring) and is writing the file 'bus' BUT the 1st line of the 'bus' file is not the hex has been swapped for the 'new' hex it has swapped out 'new' as a text value instead.

Comment: Just like with your previous question, nobody has any idea what you actually mean by "see data in the same format that python does", which is why you aren't getting any answers. Please give us an example of what the input to your program will be and what you expect the output to look like. The code you've posted is such a godawful mess that I quite frankly can't be bothered to figure out what it does.

Comment: "A picture is worth a thousand words" editor Arthur Brisbane. Unfortunately, stackoverflow won't allow me to post a simple 10 line hexedit png. This would illustrate the point exactly. When a windows exe program is opened with hexedit in its default configuration, the left pane displays an 8 byte line, the right pane displays the same data as text. The problem: 0x00 and 0x20 appear the same in the right pane. Therefore there are instances where you set the search string as a hex string to search for and instances where you set the search string as a text string to search.

Comment: It looks like you're still writing the data encoded as ASCII hex strings to a file instead of calling `unhexlify()` to change it to the binary data represented by those hex strings.